# What is "industrial ethernet"?

Tags: ethernet

When a teacher introduced it to us he gave the impression that it specifically covers some Siemens technology; that it's even a Siemens trademark.

I believe the term covers something more general, but I haven't been able to find a useful definition from a credible source.

Comment: Why don’t you ask the teacher for a definition of this term he uses. Most teachers are happy about actual interaction and questions.

Comment: @eckes: Sadly I believe the teacher is not quite competent to teach the subject, but generally I agree with your advice.

Comment: Sadly schoolwork and education questions are off-topic here

Comment: @Mike Pennington. Your comment seems sort of taunting/offensive. But I really don't see which part of my question/comment would warrant that? If you delete your comment, then I will delete this one.

Comment: I’m stating a fact... if you find facts offensive I don’t know how to respond

Comment: Can you provide a link to community guidelines that says schoolwork and education questions are off-topic?

Comment: https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic (read the off-topic section)

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you can post and accept your own answer.

Comment: I cant pick one (as they are mutually exclusive, and I obviously dont know which is more correct). If you like, I can flip a coin?

Answer (score 33):

Like many IT terms, it's primarily a marketing term.  It usually refers to Ethernet switches that are designed for harsh environments (*i.e.* industrial).  The switches may have higher temperature tolerances, electrostatic hardening, shock resistance, etc.

But they're still Ethernet switches, and they function like any other.

And other manufacturers use the same term.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/95190/discussion-on-answer-by-ron-trunk-what-is-industrial-ethernet).

Answer (score 20):

> Industrial Ethernet is the use of Ethernet in an industrial
>   environment with protocols that provide determinism and real-time
>   control. Protocols for Industrial Ethernet include EtherCAT,
>   EtherNet/IP, PROFINET, POWERLINK, SERCOS III, CC-Link IE, and Modbus
>   TCP.Many Industrial Ethernet protocols use a modified Media Access
>   Control (MAC) layer to provide low latency and determinism.
>
> Industrial Ethernet can also refer to the use of standard Ethernet
>   protocols with rugged connectors and extended temperature switches in
>   an industrial environment, for automation or process control.
>   Components used in plant process areas must be designed to work in
>   harsh environments of temperature extremes, humidity, and vibration
>   that exceed the ranges for information technology equipment intended
>   for installation in controlled environments. The use of fiber-optic
>   Ethernet variants reduces the problems of electrical noise and
>   provides electrical isolation.

Refer from [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Industrial_Ethernet).

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/95139/discussion-on-answer-by-infra-what-is-industrial-ethernet).

Answer (score 2):

Many older Automation systems used non-ethernet standards. Siemens used a PROFIBUS standard and Rockwell had a standard called Data Highway Plus. The problem with these older standards is that they were proprietary, expensive, and could not support a lot of bandwidth. It was also difficult to go across long distances.

Thus the Industrial Ethernet term is a way to differentiate from the older technologies that are still used at many corporations due to the cost of replacing.

Industrial Ethernet components typically use DIN rails that can be mounted in the same chassis next to PLCs and use the same power supplies.

Comment: Profibus is hardly proprietary. You can run Profibus on all major PLC's. I've used it on Siemens, Mitsubishi and Phoenix PLCs. It's a fairly standardized protocol, with multivendor support.

Comment: Also is not true about Profibus that can go across long distance and is slow.

Comment: Profibus maxes out at 12MBit I believe. Industrial Ethernet is typically 1000MBit. That would make it 83 times slower.